# Rust: modify values in Vec with other values in Vec

Tags: rust

Given this code:

```
let sides = vec![2, 3, 8];

let area = sides
    .iter()
    .map(|x| x) // how can i access other members of sides here?
    .sum::<u32>();

println!("area: {}", area);
```

Assuming sides is filled with values representing `width`, `height`, and `length`, how can I modify the `.map()` line to `length * width`, `width * height`, and `height * length`?

Playground available [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e0ebfd2822c9697440e2a9e0f8bd3d78).

Comment: Why do you want to use `map` for this if the array is always three simple values with different meanings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this approach:

```
let res = sides
    .iter()
    .enumerate()
    .map(|(i, val)| {
        let mut j = i + 1;
        if j == sides.len() { j = 0 }

        val * sides[j];
    })
    .sum::<u32>();
```